# unablle to send email via node-mailer | Invalid sender "emailid@gmail.com>"

Tags: express, gmail, nodemailer

I'm using express, nodemailer, & express to test sending email via gmail account. But for some reason I'm unable to send it. Also the account email and password is 100% correct, still Im getting this error. Error doesnt tell where's the issue.

Also i've already "Turn on" the gmail settings i.e lowered down the settings for apps.

I haven't used  http://nodemailer.com/2-0-0-beta/using-oauth2/    Do I need to use that even when im logged into the browser with this email id ?

I do need to develop this without using the browser but I want to see it working before.

{ [Error: Invalid sender "**********@gmail.com>"] code: 'EENVELOPE', command: 'API' }
/Users/jay/code/gmailSendEmail/app.js:43
        res.json({yo: 'error'});
           ^

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var nodeMailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport();

console.log ( ' coming here 1');



var router = express.Router();
app.use('/sayHello', router);
router.post('/', handleSayHello); // handle the route at yourdomain.com/sayHello

function handleSayHello(req, res) {
    // Not the movie transporter!
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: '****@gmail.com', // Your email id
            pass: '*****' // Your password
        }
    });


var mailOptions = {
    from: '*****@gmail.com>', // sender address
    to: '*****@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Email Example', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ' //, // plaintext body
    // html: '<b>Hello world ✔</b>' // You can choose to send an HTML body instead
};


console.log ( ' coming here 2');

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    console.log ( ' beginning emial sending '); 
    if(error){
        console.log('got - error here');        
        console.log(error);
        res.json({yo: 'error'});
    }else{
        console.log ( 'no error emial sending ')
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        res.json({yo: info.response});
    };
});

}

handleSayHello();
```

Answer (score 10):

Just remove the '>' from the **from**

```
var mailOptions = {
    from: '*****@gmail.com', // sender address
    to: '*****@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Email Example', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ' //, // plaintext body
    // html: '<b>Hello world ✔</b>' // You can choose to send an HTML body instead
};
```